# angularjs format date not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to 2015-04-17 12:44:38.0 to dd/MM/yyyy format in angularjs

```
<td ng-bind="item.MON_FE_DUEDATE | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"></td>
```

But still showing 2015-04-17 12:44:38.0 only.Please suggested to me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are trying to format it on a string.

Please see working fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/p7gz0opm/

Converted string to Date.

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date('2015-04-17 12:44:38.0 ');
}
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    {{date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}<br />
    {{date}}    
</div>
```

**Edit :**

In your case you will have to pass through a function. 
Please see another fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/qjs1uj37/

```
$scope.parth=function(str){
        return new Date(str);
    }
```

Comment: Angular converts valid ISO 8601 to dates automatically. So it can work with strings, they just have to be in a valid format. You have a good answer nonetheless.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren correct and totally agree, but if u see his answer that is not ISO 8601 format. There's a space in between. It has to be something like 2015-04-17T12:44:38.0 And thanks :)

Comment: Can you please give example for using ng-bind  ng-bind="item.MON_FE_DUEDATE | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"

Comment: @j.Doe what you have in your OP works. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yt04ztr/31/). You just need to have a correct date.

Comment: Thanks sir @Giovani Vercauteren

Comment: Thanks sir @Parth Ghiya